# ServiceStack Redis latest list by date

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, redis, servicestack

If I have a class

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ShortDesc { get; set; }
    public DataTime UpateDate { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way of getting list of users from Redis cache based on UpdateDate?

I saw numerous number of examples for Latest lists from Redis but all they assume that latest element added to list is the newest and than it is supper easy to get list of recent entries.

But In my case I need to have a list or recently updated articles based on update date e.g.

Journalist adds an Article (Id 1 ) with today's date early in the morning and than realises that he has missed a news (Id 2) from yesterday which needs to be on the website with backdated date. After that he adds a new article with today's date (Id 3)

So my feed should lists:

- Article Id 3
- Article Id 1
- Article Id 2

What is the best way achieving this with Redis?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by maintaining an index of ids in a sorted list, sorted by date.

As an example well store a list of articles with different modified dates, e.g:

```
var articles = new[]
{
    new Article { Id = 1, Title = "Article 1", ModifiedDate = new DateTime(2015, 01, 02) },
    new Article { Id = 2, Title = "Article 2", ModifiedDate = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01) },
    new Article { Id = 3, Title = "Article 3", ModifiedDate = new DateTime(2015, 01, 03) },
};
```

We can store all article POCO's in redis by storing them with a typed redis client, e.g:

```
var redisArticles = Redis.As<Article>();
redisArticles.StoreAll(articles);
```

Then everytime you store an article, also store the article id with the Modified Date as the sort value. Since the sort value needs to be a numeric or string value we'll use ticks to convert the Date into a numeric value:

```
const string LatestArticlesSet = "urn:Article:modified";

foreach (var article in articles)
{
    Redis.AddItemToSortedSet(LatestArticlesSet, article.Id.ToString(), article.ModifiedDate.Ticks);
}
```

Now to get the list articles by modified date we can fetch all the article ids by date value in descending order (i.e by latest date):

```
var articleIds = Redis.GetAllItemsFromSortedSetDesc(LatestArticlesSet);
```

Prints dump of ids:

```
articleIds.PrintDump();

[
    3,
    1,
    2
]
```

You can then fetch all the articles by the returned ids:

```
var latestArticles = redisArticles.GetByIds(articleIds);
latestArticles.PrintDump();
```

Comment: Thanks will try this solution. So just to confirm this command
redisArticles.GetByIds(articleIds)
will return articles in order of IDs in articleIds